# How to enable systemd support

Tags: systemd

I have built a system with Yocto 2.4.2 supporting systemd.
But there are some issues seemed to be missed in my configurations leading to failure of kernel starting. Any one can help ?

```
  DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
  VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if you had the same problem as this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039582/kernel-booting-frozen-due-to-mounting-failure

Comment: Perhaps, you should change your bootargs from "ro" to "rw" when you try to boot with mmc. Hope that help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*systemd* and *cgroup* should be enabled together

- systemd manager (local.conf)

  DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"

  VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
- For systemd handler (defconfig)

  CONFIG_FHANDLE=y #for systemd
- cgroups is required by systemd (defconfig)

  CONFIG_CGROUPS=y

  CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER=y

  CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS=y

  CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE=y

  CONFIG_CPUSETS=y

  CONFIG_PROC_PID_CPUSET=y

  CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT=y

  CONFIG_PAGE_COUNTER=y

  CONFIG_MEMCG=y

  CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED=y

  CONFIG_NAMESPACES=y

  CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS=y

Answer (score 1):

I had to enable cgroups in defconfig :)