# Kernel booting frozen due to mounting failure

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, systemd, fstab

I built a new yocto image for a custom board. I flashed it to an SD card and tried booting it, but freezes while booting Kernel.  [image: Boot Log]

The image has SYSTEMD feature enabled. If I disable SYSTEMD, it boots fine. Do i need to configure anything ? like in fstab? I am stuck at this point for a long time, so please advice.

Comment: That error occurs when systemd fails to mount the “API filesystems” like `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys/fs/cgroup`, etc. – perhaps your kernel doesn’t have some of the modules required for that?

Comment: Note that there is a different error message for mounting the “early” API filesystems `/sys`, `/proc`, `/dev`, and `/sys/kernel/security`, so the error has to be in one of the other ones. See [`mount-setup.c`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v239/src/core/mount-setup.c#L59-L106) for the full list of API mount points.

Comment: Thank you. I will check about your points tomorrow. It might also be related to this ?[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903680/how-to-enable-systemd-support].  How to check if my Kernel has these modules enabled or not? defconfig? and if Kernel doesnt support some API fs how to disable it ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error. I enabled CONFIG_CGROUPS related features as mentioned in ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903680/how-to-enable-systemd-support])) in my machine's defconfig and the Kernel boots fine :)